# Dynamically mapping a model to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view working with a strongly typed model. Is it possible to map my model to my partial view on the fly in a html helper method and return the rendered html?

Here is the pseudo code that I'm wondering if it's possible.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ContentRating(this HtmlHelper html, ContentKey contentKey)
    {
        ContentRatingModel contentRatingModel = new ContentRatingHelper().GetContentRatingModel(contentKey);

        // map my partial view which is named "ContentRating.cshtml" to contentRatingModel    

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("the html output of mapping");
    }
```

And use this helper method in my views as below:

```
@Html.ContentRating(ContentKey.Test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what exactly you mean by *mapping a partial view to a model* but if you want to render the contents of this partial view inside your helper you could do the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ContentRating(this HtmlHelper html, ContentKey contentKey)
{
    ContentRatingModel contentRatingModel = new ContentRatingHelper().GetContentRatingModel(contentKey);

    var result = html.Partial("ContentRating", contentRatingModel);

    return new MvcHtmlString(result.ToHtmlString());
}
```

Don't forget to bring the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace in scope so that the Partial extension method could be resolved in your custom helper:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Comment: Thank a lot. That was what I'm looking for. I'm gonna accept your answer in 7 minutes. :)